# Distance calculation in pandas dataframe with two lat columns and two long columns

Tags: python, pandas, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a pandas Dataframe df with these 4 colums :

- pickup_latitude
- pickup_longitude
- dropoff_latitude
- dropoff_longitude

And I want to create a new column with the distance between the pickup and the dropoff point.

I created this function :

```
def calcul_de_distance_vol_oiseau(data):

R = 6373.0

""" je change les variables en radians car python parle en radian et pas en degrées """
data['pickup_longitude'] = data['pickup_longitude'].apply(radians)
data['pickup_latitude'] = data['pickup_latitude'].apply(radians)
data['dropoff_longitude'] = data['dropoff_longitude'].apply(radians)
data['dropoff_latitude'] = data['dropoff_latitude'].apply(radians)

data['diff_lon'] = data['dropoff_longitude'] - data['pickup_longitude']
data['diff_lat'] = data['dropoff_latitude'] - data['dropoff_latitude']

data['calcul_intermediaire']= (data['diff_lat'] / 2).apply(sin)**2 + data['pickup_latitude'].apply(cos) * data['dropoff_latitude'].apply(cos) * (data['diff_lon'] / 2).apply(sin)**2

data['distance'] = R*np.arctan2((data['calcul_intermediaire']).apply(sqrt),(1 - data['calcul_intermediaire']).apply(sqrt))

return data
```

But when I want to verify the distance between my points, I don't have the same result as in this website https://www.sunearthtools.com/fr/tools/distance.php which calcul distance between gps points.
I think there is a mathematical error in my function but I didn't find where.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `radians`? Imported, self-defined, what exactly?

Comment: Imported with this line : `from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians`

Comment: Have you tried using the `numpy` equivalents instead? Pandas is made to be used with NumPy, not with the (single-float) `math` functions.

Comment: Didn't know that, I will try to find a way with numpy. Maybe this is the solution

Comment: I get this error `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'data'` at the line : `data['calcul_intermediaire']= sin(np.data['diff_lat'] / 2)**2 + data['pickup_latitude'].apply(cos) * data['dropoff_latitude'].apply(cos) * sin(np.data['diff_lon'] / 2)**2`

Comment: `sin(np.data['diff_lat'] / 2)**2` will not work. Using `np.sin`, `np.cos` and simply `data`. etc will work. The *functions* are from numpy, not your data. You're attempting the equivalent of `sin(math.data...)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need only:

```
data['pickup_longitude'] = data['pickup_longitude'].apply(radians)
```

and similar code for the other columns (using lambda or defining a function).

Comment: Can you help me for `data['calcul_intermediaire']` and `data['distance']`, especially for `dlat` and `dlon` and `atan2`

Comment: It is really similar, for example: sin(dlat / 2)**2 should be (dlat.apply(sin) / 2 )**2 because dlat is an array.

Comment: but atan2 has two parameters

Comment: `(dlat.apply(sin) / 2 )**2` is not correct because sin(a/b) is not equal to sin(a)/b. And this is what you did

Comment: ((dlat /2).apply(sin))**2 or np.sin(dlat/2)**2

Comment: For atan2 use numpy.arctan2

Comment: Ok now the function works, i need to verify is the distance are the true ones

Comment: The distance are not the good ones I think. I may have a problem in my calculations

Answer (score 1):

(Late answer but ...)
I suggest you use geopy.distance vincenty
, define a function to interface it from pandas
and create the new dateframe column using this function:

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

def pandasVincenty(row):
    '''calculate distance (m) between two lat&long points using the Vincenty formula '''

    return vincenty((row.pickup_latitude, row.pickup_longitude), (row.dropoff_latitude, row.dropoff_longitude)).meters 


data['distance'] =  data.apply(lambda r: pandasVincenty(r), axis=1)
```

This uses degrees as input and gives meters as output...

Answer (score 1):

This worked, you can also use geopy.distance.distance():

```
>>def distance(row):
    >>>return geopy.distance.distance((row.start_lats, row.start_longs),(row.end_lats, row.end_longs)).mi

>>new_df['miles_traveled']= new_df.apply(lambda r: distance(r), axis=1)
```